# Git Bash/SCM issue with 100% disk usage

Tags: git, hard-drive, disk-access

After using VS Code and running the bash terminal with some simple npm commands, I quickly see that my disk drive usage jumps from the typical 2%-5% up to 100% and it holds it there constantly.
Even after I close VS code and shut down all np builds, json servers, etc. the disk usage still stays at 99%-100%.
The only way to stop this is to manually go in task manager and kill the 'Git for Windows' process.
Why does this occur? Any ideas what might be causing this spike in disk usage?

Comment: Complete guess...Do you have npm directories ignored in your .gitignore (you probably should)? If no, maybe you just downloaded multiple GBs of npm packages and Git is trying to calculate stuff about them all, and didn't finish yet?

Comment: I do have the folders from the dependencies in a .gitignore, but I think you might be right about this, perhaps there are some other files that are constantly being sent perhaps from the npm ones

Comment: The issue is we have to be careful with main directories and always have .gitignore file because git will automatically start parsing through all the files and including everything that's in the directory and out of the .gitignore